# Building multidimensional array with input from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, php-7.3

It works fine creating level-1, but when level-2 is being created, it only updates the first letter of index [1].

**Code:**

```
// Position [Level-1]
$taxonomy_id = [
  "id_no_1",
  "id_no_2",
  "id_no_3",
];

// Position [Level-2]
$titles = [
  "title_1",
  "title_2",
  "title_3",
];

$array = [];


for ($i = 0; $i < count($taxonomy_id); $i++) {

//Construct level-1
$array[] = $taxonomy_id["{$i}"];

//Construct level-2
$array["{$i}"]["{$i}"] = $titles["{$i}"];

}

print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
(
    [0] => td_no_1
    [1] => it_no_2
    [2] => id_no_3
)
```

**Wanted result:**

```
Array
(
    [id_no_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title_1
        )

    [id_no_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title_2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off creating the sub arrays in one go, you can also simplify `"{$i}"` with `$i`...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($taxonomy_id); $i++) {
    $array[$taxonomy_id[$i]] = [$titles[$i]];
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add 2 sub-levels using the same for loop?
I intended to add a separate question but my question quota for the day is breached.